# How Do I stop Magento from sending a double opt-in email for newsletter subscription? I want Mailchimp's only

Tags: magento2, customer-account, confirmation, mailchimp

I use Magento 2 and Mailchimp. Whenever I have "**Need to confirm**" set to **YES**, new subscribers get two emails asking them to confirm their email -- one from **Magento** and another from **Mailchimp**.

Because the one from Mailchimp appears in the customer's inbox (as against the promotions tab for Magento) I'd like for the customer to get just the one from Mailchimp.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?